# Typescript: Property 'DB' does not exist on type 'Global'

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my `src/app.ts`, I have:

```
import DB from '../models'
```

And in `src/models/index.ts`, I have:

```
export default (() => {
    if (global.DB) {
        return global.DB
    }
    ...
    // Do some other stuff
    return something
```

My `typings/global.d.ts` has:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        DB: any;
    }
}

declare var DB: any;
```

And finally, my `tsconfig.json` has:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "files": [
        "typings/*"
    ]
}
```

But I still get the error:

```
Error: src/models/index.ts(7,16): error TS2339: Property 'DB' does not exist on type 'Global'.
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Shoud'nt index.ts import global?

Comment: Not sure - how would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` is probably wrong. You're using both `files` and `include` to specify globs. `files` however is supposed to be used for [specific (relative or absolute) paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details) whereas `include` can be used with globs.

If you merged the two paths into `include`, like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./built",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*",
      "./typings/*"
  ]
}
```

your files should compile.